# Make a home view for application

Tags: iphone, ios, uicontrol

Hi guys i am very eager to know that how we can make a view like in this application having different icons calling different viewcontrollers and edit button to add shorcuts to tab bar at the bottom. Any tutorial link will be appreciated .

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats a really long view, why would you want that? Unless you are putting that into a UIScrollView..

Check [Three20 Launcher](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher), it may suit your needs, and it is widely used in many apps.

Comment: +1 ... yeah, good reference. I personally am regretful of my use of Three20... but that's just a personal preference thing. Seems like it really introduced a lot of complexity, and I didn't get that much out of it I couldn't have done myself (without the hastle of jumping through all the hoops required to maintain the Three20 dependency).... but it seems like this might be a good link for the OP.

Comment: I think that the implementation of their Lanucher is quite simple, and making it from zero would take anyone at least more than the Three20 setup time. What you say about updating Three20 is true, but there is a script included that imports all the stuff needed to your project, and if you can set up a repository that should handle updates automatically.

Comment: @Nicholas S; Did you have to go through their XCode 4 "Update" process?

Comment: What do you mean by THEIR XCode update? when they update something the repository is updated, so you just have to update your copy using GIT

Comment: That's a no then... because that was not the case at all. It was a disaster. Not to mention if you wanted to use LLVM. http://www.amirnaor.com/?p=112

Comment: 4 month delay to fix LLVM warnings: https://github.com/facebook/three20/issues/259 - Look, I'm not saying it's a bad link - I upvoted it - I'm just saying, dev beware. It's not that bad to recreate that in a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial for using the UITabBarController: http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/

Which seems like what you're asking for.

It will allow you to have a "More" button which gives you the view you're looking for.

Otherwise, seems like if you need more control, what you're looking for could be accomplished fairly simply with a UIScrollView and some UIImageViews. There are two great videos on using UIScrollView in the developer videos section of the apple dev site. (They open up in iTunes) http://developer.apple.com/videos/

Comment: thanks for the link steve but Nicolas gave me the lin for what i was looking for =)